# Is there a way to search for multiple terms in admin search? django

Tags: django, django-admin, django-search-lucene

In the django admin search bar if i had a model with a column = fruit_name
and I wanted to search that column for all instances with either the fruit_name = banana or apple which would show all of the bananas and apples, how could I do that?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Override the [ModelAdmin.get_search_results](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_search_results)` method:

```
from operator import or_
from django.db.models import Q

class MyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...
    def get_search_results(self, request, queryset, search_term):
        queryset, use_distinct = super(MyAdmin, self).get_search_results(
                                               request, queryset, search_term)
        search_words = search_term.split()
        if search_words:
            q_objects = [Q(**{field + '__icontains': word})
                                for field in self.search_fields
                                for word in search_words]
            queryset |= self.model.objects.filter(reduce(or_, q_objects))
    return queryset, use_distinct
```

Comment: A useful option here is to define a delimiter (i.e., `, ` [comma-space]) and add this to `split`. `search_words = search_term.split(", ")`. This allows you to manually delimit the search terms.

Comment: Where did you get `reduce` from?

Comment: In python 2.7 `reduce` is a built-in function. In python 3 you have to import it from `functools`.

Answer (score 2):

In your admin.py file you can customize the presentation of the models.

```
class YourModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
       list_display = ('id_proveedor','anio','mes','fecha','fecha_mod','contacto','usuario','obs')
       list_display_links = ('id_proveedor','anio','mes','fecha','fecha_mod','contacto','usuario','obs')
       list_filter = ('id_proveedor','anio','mes')
       ordering = ['id_proveedor']
       search_fields = ('id_proveedor','anio','mes','contacot')
       list_per_page = 10

admin.site.register(YourModel, YourModelAdmin)
```

You can customize for what fields you want the search, the fields you wanna display, the ordering etc.

check the documentation about the [admin page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/admin/)

Answer (score 1):

In my case, using @catavaran's answer would break filters as asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64571673/3091595). I came up with the following work-around:

```py
from operator import or_
from django.db.models import Q

class MyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...
    def get_search_results(self, request, queryset, search_term):
        orig_queryset = queryset
        queryset, use_distinct = super(MyAdmin, self).get_search_results(
                                               request, queryset, search_term)
        search_words = search_term.split()
        if search_words:
            q_objects = [Q(**{field + '__icontains': word})
                                for field in self.search_fields
                                for word in search_words]
            queryset |= self.model.objects.filter(reduce(or_, q_objects))

    queryset = queryset & orig_queryset

    return queryset, use_distinct
```

This makes sure that ant previous filtering is not overridden when we use `queryset |= self.model.objects.filter(reduce(or_, q_objects))`. The use of `orig_queryset`, on the other hand, ensures that any chosen filters also get applied.