# How to override Django get_search_results method in ModelAdmin, while keeping filters working as expected?

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-filter

I have a Model admin where I override `get_search_result` this way

```py
def get_search_results(self, request, queryset, search_term):
        queryset, use_distinct = super(OccupancyAdmin, self).get_search_results(
            request, queryset, search_term
        )
        search_words = search_term.split(",")
        if search_words:
            q_objects = [
                Q(**{field + "__icontains": word})
                for field in self.search_fields
                for word in search_words
            ]
            queryset |= self.model.objects.filter(reduce(or_, q_objects))
        return queryset, use_distinct
```

The suggestion comes from here: [Is there a way to search for multiple terms in admin search? django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28099848/is-there-a-way-to-search-for-multiple-terms-in-admin-search-django)

The problem I am facing is the following: neither the `DateTimeRangeFilter` from `rangefilter` nor my custom `SimpleListFilter` work as expected anymore. The filters seem like being disabled.

I looked at the SQL queries being performed and they seem alright.

I am pretty sure I am messing up with the querysets somehow but don't know how to debug this.

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me was declaring an original queryset **before** the super(), and finally doing an interception of both querysets:

```py
def get_search_results(self, request, queryset, search_term):
    orig_queryset = queryset
    queryset, use_distinct = super().get_search_results(request, queryset, search_term)
    search_words = search_term.split(",")
    if search_words:
        q_objects = [
            Q(**{field + "__icontains": word})
            for field in self.search_fields
            for word in search_words
        ]
        queryset |= self.model.objects.filter(reduce(or_, q_objects))

    queryset = queryset & orig_queryset

    return queryset, use_distinct
```

Otherwise, using @simon-spa's answer any modifications performed via the modified `get_search_results()` would be ignored (but filters would indeed work).

Answer (score 1):

Django first applies filters and then passes the resulting queryset to the search method. In your code, you are adding additional objects to the queryset via `self.model.objects.filter()` which basically renders the filter useless.

If you apply the filter only to the current queryset it works:

```py
def get_search_results(self, request, queryset, search_term):
    queryset, use_distinct = super().get_search_results(request, queryset, search_term)
    search_words = search_term.split(",")
    if search_words:
        q_objects = [
            Q(**{field + "__icontains": word})
            for field in self.search_fields
            for word in search_words
        ]
        queryset = queryset.filter(reduce(or_, q_objects))
    return queryset, use_distinct
```